# What does this: s[s[1:] == s[:-1]] do in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I've been looking for a way to efficiently check for duplicates in a numpy array and stumbled upon a question that contained an answer using this code.

What does this line mean in numpy?

```
s[s[1:] == s[:-1]]
```

Would like to understand the code before applying it. Looked in the Numpy doc but had trouble finding this information.

Answer (score 27):

The slices `[1:]` and `[:-1]` mean *all but the first* and *all but the last* elements of the array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = np.array((1, 2, 2, 3))  # four element array
>>> s[1:]
array([2, 2, 3])  # last three elements
>>> s[:-1]
array([1, 2, 2])  # first three elements
```

therefore the comparison generates an array of boolean comparisons between each element `s[x]` and its *"neighbour"* `s[x+1]`, which will be one shorter than the original array (as the last element has no neighbour):

```
>>> s[1:] == s[:-1]
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

and using that array to index the original array gets you the elements where the comparison is `True`, i.e. the elements that are the same as their neighbour:

```
>>> s[s[1:] == s[:-1]]
array([2])
```

Note that this only identifies **adjacent** duplicate values.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough explanation :D. Will accept asap. So I guess to find all dups, sort and then do this :D.

Comment: @zehelvion yes, if the array is unsorted you will need to sort first for this method to find all duplicates.

Comment: Shouldn't the array being sorted a requirement?

Comment: @gabhijit not necessarily, you may only *want* to find adjacent duplicates

Comment: Tried to use a regular (non-numpy) list of booleans (i.e. a mask) to index a regular list. That didn't work of course.  So I went for this instead: `[x for (x,y) in zip(my_list, mask) if y]`. Thought I'd document it here, although it doesn't look for equal adjacent elements of course.

Answer (score 8):

Check this out:

```
>>> s=numpy.array([1,3,5,6,7,7,8,9])
>>> s[1:] == s[:-1]
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> s[s[1:] == s[:-1]]
array([7])
```

So `s[1:]` gives all numbers but the first, and `s[:-1]` all but the last.
Now compare these two vectors, e.g. look if two adjacent elements are the same. Last, select these elements.

Answer (score 3):

`s[1:] == s[:-1]` compares `s` without the first element with `s` without the last element, i.e. 0th with 1st, 1st with 2nd etc, giving you an array of `len(s) - 1` boolean elements. `s[boolarray]` will select only those elements from `s` which have `True` at the corresponding place in `boolarray`. Thus, the code extracts all elements that are equal to the next element.

Answer (score 3):

It will show duplicates in a sorted array.

Basically, the inner expression `s[1:] == s[:-1]` compares the array with its shifted version. Imagine this:

```
1, [2, 3, ... n-1, n  ]
-  [1, 2, ... n-2, n-1] n
=> [F, F, ...   F, F  ]
```

In a sorted array, there will be no `True` in resulted array unless you had repetition. Then, this expression `s[array]` filters those which has `True` in the index `array`.